# Jquery modal dialog box as login then redirect page

Tags: php, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Good day to all,

I am using PHP and jquery modal dialog box as log in to my page then I want to redirect to another page. But what happen is once I redirect to another page, it displays on my modal box. But then I tried closing the modal but I cannot redirect to another page. I want to use php  `header()` to redirect page. Do you have any idea how to do this the right way? This is how I use to my login page.

```
$("form#formAction").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login-process.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("input#username").val("");
            $("input#password").val("");
            $("input#username").focus();

        }
    });
});
```

login.php

```
$data = array (
        'username' => $_POST["username"],
        'password' => $_POST["password"]
        );

$sql = "SELECT id, role FROM user WHERE username=:username AND password=:password";
$STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);
$STH->execute($data);

$data = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$role = $data[0]['role'];
$count = $STH->rowCount();

if ($count > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'YES';
    if ($role == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['role'] = 'customer';
    }

    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo "Please check your username or password again.";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you show us `login-process.php`?

Comment: There. I pasted it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you or someone else is still looking for an answer: You can't do it using php header function due to the fact that you will redirect the content requested via ajax and not the actual page. Instead, in your login-process.php file return 1 if the login can be done and the simply use the javascript function `location.reload();` to reload the page or `window.location.href="index.html"` to redirect. So your Javascript would be like this:

```
$("form#formAction").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login-process.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if(data == 1) {
                // If logged-in, reload the page or do something else
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $("input#username").val("");
                $("input#password").val("");
                $("input#username").focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a `header('Location:....')` should work

```
if ($count > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 'YES';
    if ($role == 'admin') {
        $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['role'] = 'customer';
    }

    header('Location: redirectpage.php');
} else {
    echo "Please check your username or password again.";
}
```

Comment: Could be. But that's my problem occurs. You see I use modal in my login. Then.. Once I do `header("location:page.php");` YES it will redirect but the output is inside the modal. I need to get rid of the modal first before redirecting.